# VISUAL STUDIO Custom Project Type COMPILING

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, compilation

Im thinking about one thing - I want to create a custom project type for Visual Studio and I want to create a special kind of package at build execution like for example silverlight does.  Imagine the funcionality of my project type like as it was a Silverlight project. Can you help me with this topic ? Thank you very much .

best regards.

Comment: ...Did you try googling "visual studio custom project"? From the first page of results: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Comment: thank you wise man but that doesn't answer even one part of my question .

Comment: Do you know how to configure build for a regular project? Maybe start with asking that. Then you can use the link to turn the regular project into a template, which was your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Managed Package Framework (MPF) to create your custom project system you can override the Build method in your custom ProjectNode and it should be as easy as that.
I suggest you take a look at [the MPF documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166157.aspx).
Good luck.